# All my tfs tasks invisible when used Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Suddenly all my previous and current TFS tasks are not seen when I use Visual Studio 2015.
If I use visual studio 2012 or web portal TFS, I see all my tasks.

---

> update - 06 OCT 2016 - 5:20 PM IST.

---

We did further investigation. The situation is that our company had users in TFS using Sharepoint user IDs. Later the Domain controller was introduced and everyone migrated to the domain. So now we have two users (with different domains) for the old users who were present at the time of Sharepoint user base.

We did SQL Profiler on the TFS DB while running Query from Web Portal and VS 2015 for affected user.

```
[![two users returned from TFS][1]][1]
```

[image]

then VS2015 takes the old user (Which we dont want) to find all Assigned work items as shown below

[image: VS picks up other user that we dont want]

Now IF i manually go change the query text and add FABRICAM in the domain or IF i run the query from WEB Portal, the correct user is picked up and results start showing as shown below

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Suddenly all my previous and current TFS tasks are not seen` have you ever seen the tasks when using VS2015 ?

Comment: for my user no. for other users i can see. When i build a new query where "Assiged to= {my username}" i dont see anything but if i do "Assinged to ={other username}" i see the tasks. on Visual studio 2012, I see tasks for me as well as others, no issues at all.

Comment: This seems not related to your account. Could you try to create a query assigned to you with VS2015 on another machine? If you can view the task, then the issue is more likely related to your local VS2015.

Comment: this is happening on all machines where VS2015 is installed so the issue seems to be with VS2015

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. Where are you not able to see them? Are you using a query or looking at the backlog? If query, what query? If backlog, what are your iterations? Are you part of a team?

Comment: Can you check if your username/displayname is changed?

Comment: Do you have different Projects and/or Area Paths? Then you need to connect VS to the desired one (Team Explorer, click on the top drop down with title "Connect", then |Projects and my Teams"

Answer (score 0):

This works well with my VS2015. Please double check if it can work with web portal.

[image]

Try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and try it again.

Comment: Tried clear TFS and VS cache but no luck...  
this is happening on all machines where VS2015 is installed so the issue seems to be with VS2015

Comment: Sounds impossible, all VS have problems...Are you using the same query on VS and web portal? Which value are you using for Assigned To `@Me` or `your username`? Could you share the detail info of your query?